# EXCEL VBA COMPARING 2 COLUMN

Tags: vba, excel

[[image]
I have 2 list with firstname and Lastname, now I want to know if someone in list1 exist at the list2 (References)

this is the Code that I'm using Right Now but the problem is (Picture3 References)

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant

    Set CompareRange = Range("E1:F6")

    For Each x In Selection
        For Each y In CompareRange
            If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

I want A result Like (Picture4 References)

where I only Get to those whose Firstname and Lastname are The same

NOTE: At (picture 3 & 4) my code change

```
  Set CompareRange = Range("G2:H7")
```

Comment: Pictures are missing

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation to post Image :(

Comment: can you just Click the Image Link please :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this as well

```
Sub Find_Matches()
    Dim list1 As Range
    Dim list2 As Range
    Set list1 = Range("A1:B6")
    Set list2 = Range("E1:F6")

    For Each row1 In list1.Rows
        For Each row2 In list2.Rows
            If (row1.Cells(1) = row2.Cells(1) And row1.Cells(2) = row2.Cells(2)) Then
            row1.Cells(1).Offset(0, 2) = row1.Cells(1)
            row1.Cells(2).Offset(0, 2) = row1.Cells(2)
            Exit For
            End If
        Next row2

    Next row1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

**No need for VBA**

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

Put this formula in cell `C1`

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1&"|"&B1,$E$1:$E$6&"|"&$F$1:$F$6,0)),"",A1)
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and drag the formula down.

Put this formula in cell `D1` and pull the formula down

```
=IF(C1<>"",B1,"")
```

This is the end result

[image]

**Logic**:

1. We are performing a two-column lookup using the `&` operator
2. We are using "|" to prevent any false positives. For example "Name1N" Col `A` and "ame2" in Col B which after concatenating would be the same as that for "Name1" Col `A` and "Name2"
3. In Col `D` we are just checking if Col `C` is populated. If it is then simply pull the values from Col `B`
4. The first formula is an array formula and hence we are using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in lieu of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>